# Is there a name for trying to divine hidden meaning from clear communications?

Tags: epistemology

I'm not sure if this is a philosophy question, but it seems to fall within the domain of epistemology, so I thought I'd try to get an answer here.  My question arises from several questions I have seen on [academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) where students try to divine some hidden unstated meaning from basic clear-cut communications.  For example, [a recent question on academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/122518/invited-for-a-campus-interview-without-letter-of-recommendation) went like this:

> **Question:** I was recently invited to an on-campus interview after having a skype interview.  I noticed, after checking with my referees, that this particular school did not request letters of recommendation for me.  I found this odd, any ideas on what it might mean?
>
> **Answer in comments:** That they want to interview you...

I see many cases like this where people have difficulty accepting clear-cut communications, and seem to bend over backwards to try to find some hidden meaning that is just not there.  **Is there a name for this type of quixotic quest for hidden meaning?**

Comment: This seems more like a question for English.SE.

Comment: Paranoia, no? At any rate this sounds like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_bias and may even in certain circumstances qualify as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy

Comment: [Suspicion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suspicion).

Comment: But see also [Conspiracy theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conspiracy_theory).

Comment: Looks like a good answer to me. I'm not sure I see the problem.

Comment: *Percipience.* https://www.etymonline.com/word/perceive#etymonline_v_12665 Being careful, wise, thoughtful, analytical, thorough, mature. (All antonyms for *superficial*). *c. 1300, via Anglo-French parceif, Old North French *perceivre (Old French perçoivre) "perceive, notice, see; recognize, understand," from Latin percipere "obtain, gather, seize entirely, take possession of," also, figuratively, "to grasp with the mind, learn, comprehend," literally "to take entirely," from per "thoroughly" (see per) + capere "to grasp, take," from PIE root *kap- "to grasp."*

Comment: i like the question, but agree that it's better suited to another stackexchange, unless you want to ask about philosophers who have written about it?

Comment: I just thought it might be an informal fallacy of some kind, so thought I'd ask it here in the first instance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermeneutics_of_suspicion just a guess

Comment: It is the flip side of [Apophenia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophenia) "*a universal human tendency to seek patterns in random information*", a cognitive bias. It is an evolutionary adaptation - better to mistake light and shadows for a tiger than to miss a tiger hidden in the bushes. But the question is more suited for [Psychology SE](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Several answers are offered in the comments section, but most do not quite fit with what I am looking for.  The closest concept to what I am looking for seems to be what has been called the "[hermeneutics of suspicion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermeneutics_of_suspicion)" (hat tip to confused to pointing out this one).  Felski (2011) describes it this way:

> The “hermeneutics of suspicion” is the name usually bestowed on this technique of reading texts against the grain and between the lines, of cataloging their omissions and laying bare their contradictions, of rubbing in what they fail to know and cannot represent.  ...  The critic probes for meanings inaccessible to authors as well as ordinary readers, and exposes the text’s complicity in social conditions that it seeks to deny or disavow.  Context, as the ampler, more expansive reference point, will invariably trump the claims of the individual text, knowing it far better than it can ever know itself.

This concept gets most of the way to encapsulating what I am looking for, but it not does not necessarily indicate the quixotic nature of the inquiry in the cases that interest me here.  Nevertheless, if appears to be the closest philosophical concept to what I am looking for.